# Existence of a closed and open set in 0-dimensional Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

Given $T = 0-$dimensional (i.e, T has a basis of sets which are both open and closed), Lindelof Hausdorff space, with closed subsets $A$ and $B$ such that $A\cap B = \emptyset$. Prove that $\exists$ a closed and open set (clopen) set $D$ with $A\subset D$ and $B\cap D =\emptyset$.

I have thought of this problem for a while, but haven't been able to make any good progress. Can someone please give some detailed help, if possible, on this tricky problem?

Comment: The question is not an exact duplicate, but Alex Ravsky's posted answer is explicitly for this more general situation.

Comment: Many thanks for your great help, Mr. Fischer:)